# shall script: merge files, how to add some characters at the beginning of each line of awk output

Tags: bash, awk, command-line, merge

I am trying to merge hundreds of samples files that contain species names and proportions into one file in long-format using bash script. I wonder how to add some characters at the beginning of each line of awk output.

I have some sampleID that I saved in the variable `$STEM`. I used `awk` to get the species names and proportions from each file. Proportion is at the beginning of each line; species name is at the end (6th place) of each line (tab-separated). But I also want to add the sampleID (`$STEM`) to the beginning of each line in the output file. Here is my code:

```
for file in $input_dir/*_species_abundance.txt
do
        STEM=$(basename "$file" _species_abundance.txt )
        echo "processing sample $STEM"
        awk '{print "$STEM," $1,$6}' FS='\t' $file >> $input_dir/merged_species_abundance.txt

done
```

The `"$STEM,"` part doesn't work as expected, because the current output is "$STEM" instead of substituting it with the sampleID.

Do you have any suggestions on how I can modify my code? Thank you in advance!

Here is some sample input:

```
  0.45  124078  0       S       148633                s__Faecalibacterium prausnitzii_D
  0.35  95476   0       S       145938                s__Faecalibacterium prausnitzii_C
  0.21  57002   0       S       158191                s__Faecalibacterium prausnitzii_I
  0.18  49503   0       S       224832                s__Faecalibacterium sp900539945
  0.07  18991   0       S       157095                s__Faecalibacterium prausnitzii_G
  0.04  12007   0       S       187396                s__Faecalibacterium prausnitzii_F
...
...
```

The first number is the proportion, and the last word is the species name.

The sampleID is something like 1001, 1002, 1003, ...

My desired output would be (comma-separate):

```
1001,0.45,s__Faecalibacterium prausnitzii_D
1001,0.35,s__Faecalibacterium prausnitzii_C
1001,0.21,s__Faecalibacterium prausnitzii_I
...
1002,0.28,s__Faecalibacterium prausnitzii_D
1002,0.00,s__Faecalibacterium prausnitzii_C
1002,0.01,s__Faecalibacterium prausnitzii_I
...
1003,0.60,s__Faecalibacterium prausnitzii_D
1003,0.02,s__Faecalibacterium prausnitzii_C
1003,0.39,s__Faecalibacterium prausnitzii_I
...
...
```

Comment: `TLDR` but from a simple glance of your `awk` code, it just need a `-v` flag to assign the shell variable. `awk -v var="$STEM"  '{print var, $1,$6} .... `

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script/19075707#19075707) answer your question? BTW, I'd also recommend switching to lower- or mixed-case shell variables, to avoid accidental conflicts with the many all-caps names that have special meaning to the shell and/or some commands.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you! I was searching for -v option in awk command. The link is very helpful. And thank you for the reminder. My colleague used STEM as the variable name, so I just kept using it... I will definitely keep your tip in mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
input_dir=mydir;
for file in $input_dir/*_species_abundance.txt;
do
    STEM=$(basename "$file" _species_abundance.txt );
    echo "processing sample $STEM";
    awk '{print '$STEM' "," $1 "," $6 " " $7}' $file; >> $input_dir/merged_species_abundance.txt
done
```

The key to printing the value of the shell environment variable, `$STEM`, is to let the shell evaluate it by "placing it outside the single quotes", `'`. Then, awk gets its value.

This is the output generated:

```
processing sample 1001
processing sample 1002
processing sample 2001
processing sample 2002
$ cat mydir/merged_species_abundance.txt
1001,0.45,s__Faecalibacterium prausnitzii_D
1001,0.35,s__Faecalibacterium prausnitzii_C
1001,0.21,s__Faecalibacterium prausnitzii_I
1001,0.18,s__Faecalibacterium sp900539945
1001,0.07,s__Faecalibacterium prausnitzii_G
1001,0.04,s__Faecalibacterium prausnitzii_F
1002,0.45,s__Faecalibacterium prausnitzii_D
1002,0.35,s__Faecalibacterium prausnitzii_C
1002,0.21,s__Faecalibacterium prausnitzii_I
1002,0.18,s__Faecalibacterium sp900539945
1002,0.07,s__Faecalibacterium prausnitzii_G
1002,0.04,s__Faecalibacterium prausnitzii_F
```

Comment: This depends on the sample ID being numeric; passing it as an awk variable (as in @Jetchisel's comment) is much safer.

Comment: Thank you! the single quote works! I will try to pass it as awk variable as well. May I ask why using awk variable is much safer?

Comment: @GordonDavisson, it doesn't depend on the sample ID being numeric. It can include text. I just tested it with a file called `he's__species_abundance.txt`, and it worked fine: `he's_,0.18,s__Faecalibacterium sp900539945`. Note that I included a `'` in the name to make it weird. I suppose that it may not handle some estrange characters if they are in the first part of the name, but I think that would be unlikely.

Comment: @LuisGuzman It doesn't work with that filename on any of the versions of `awk` I've tested with (and I don't see how it could). I get errors like `awk: 1: unexpected character '''` and `awk: syntax error at source line 1`. To get it to work, I have to add double-quotes (within the single-quotes), like: `awk '{print "'$STEM'" ...`. But to protect the variable from shell processing, it should be in double-quotes (*outside* the single-quotes), like: `awk '{print "'"$STEM"'" ...`. And that'll *still* fail under some circumstances.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, it does works with the awk on my ol7 linux vm, but I get your point.  Unusual characters on the name may break it. Also, I understand the security issue related to code injection which could be a concern in some environments. I'm not against the `-v` option. When writing scripts where the above is a concern, it is the way to go. That said, for my day to day use and the scripts that I write to make my life easier around the office, it is usually not a concern, and I don't bother.